# Django Dynamic Class

Tags: python, django

These 2 methods are equivalent.

## method 1

```
class X(object):
    a = 1
```

## method 2

```
X = type('X', (object,), dict(a=1))
```

I want to know what is the equivalent of :

```
class ObjectTable(tables.ModelTable):

    id = tables.Column(sortable=False, visible=False)
    societe = tables.Column(sortable=False, visible=False)

    class Meta:
        model = models.get_model('core', "Fournisseur")
```

I tried this but don't work :

```
ObjectTable=type('ObjectTable',(tables.ModelTable,),dict(model=myModel))
ObjectTable=type('ObjectTable',(tables.ModelTable,),dict(meta.model=myModel))
ObjectTable=type('ObjectTable',(tables.ModelTable,),dict(meta=myModel))
```

Thanks.

Comment: Seriously, it is poor form to come on here with questions of the form "How do I do x" without showing your attempt so far.

Comment: I have tryed much things without result. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: So, in what sense did this not work?

Comment: Do. Not. Do. This.  All the future programmers who attempt to maintain your programs will hate you.  What's wrong with doing things the proper way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution :

```
def CreateForm(for_model, request=None, instance=None, user=None):
    class _StateMachineBaseModelForm(ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = for_model
            exclude = ('societe',)

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(_StateMachineBaseModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            try:
                if user:
                    self.fields['banque'].queryset = Banque.objects.filter(pays=user.get_profile().societe.pays)
            except:
                pass

    if for_model: return _StateMachineBaseModelForm(request, instance=instance)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's *the exact same thing* with the values that you find in your django example. Try it for yourself.

All of your examples "do not work" as you put it, because (a) you don't create any fields other than `meta` (b) that should be spelled `Meta` (c) the value of `Meta` should be an (old style) class.

Comment: @Youssef: How is that a problem? You already know how to create members and classes.

Comment: Yes but the problem is how to create class dynamicaly with a meta data like model.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/21640/marcin : Yes but the problem is how to create class dynamicaly with a meta data like model

Comment: @Youssef: Your examples are nothing like the "normal" code you posted. That is your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Before we start, I agree with S. Lott in the comments. You almost certainly don't want to do this.

Here goes:

```
# You can't create an old-style class with type,
# so define a function that creates one.
def make_meta_class():
    class Meta:
        model = models.get_model('core', "Fournisseur")
    return Meta

# Create the dictionary (remember to include the fields as well as the meta class)
d=dict(,
    Meta=make_meta_class(),
    id=tables.Column(sortable=False, visible=False)
    societe=tables.Column(sortable=False, visible=False)
)
# Create the class dynamically
ObjectTable=type('ObjectTable', (tables.ModelTable,), d)
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you haven't gained whatever OP is seeking if you still define `Meta` using normal syntax. That said, he should be able to work for himself how to do that too.